# Testing HTML5 offline manifest on tomcat localhost

Tags: html, tomcat, caching, localhost, manifest

I am trying to test offline feature of my HTML5 / Java application. I can imagine 2 ways to simulate that locally.

1. I turn of the wi-fi / internet of my laptop.  But localhost 0 127.0.0.1 doesn't have anything to do with internet and it still keeps serving my request.
2. I stop the tomcat. In this case I get the standard browser error page (Unable to connect error message).

How could I test this on my local tomcat?

Answer (score 0):

You could try disabling your network adapter.  That would probably do it.

[Instructions for Windows](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/enable-disable-network-adapter#1TC=windows-7)

[Instructions for Linux](https://superuser.com/questions/695297/disable-network-adaptor-eth0-on-debian)

Comment: On second thought, if stopping tomcat didn't do what your looking for, this may not be that helpful.